# Run Mahout in action example lastfm

Tags: hadoop, machine-learning, mahout

I have one problem when run the Last.fm clustering example in Mahout in action book.
The issue is when I run the command :

```
--bin/mahout kmeans -i /user/local/Mia/lastfm_vector/ -o /user/local/Mia/lastfm_topics -c /user/local/Mia/lastfm_centroids -k 2000 -ow -dm org.apache.mahout.common.distance.CosineDistanceMeasure -cd 0.01 -x 20 -cl
```

I checked out the source code from git:
https://github.com/tdunning/MiA.git

```
The issue is: Exception is thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exit:/user/local/Mia/lastfm_vector
```

Everyone who help me to provide me file input Lastfm_vector to run this example. I need it for my education.
Thanks & Regard!

Comment: Did you put any data at `/user/local/Mia/lastfm_vector`?

Comment: i don't known the format of input. Can you give me some input of data formats. I'm a newbie with this. Thanks Owen

Comment: What version of Mahout are you using ? Are you using HDFS ( Hadoop ) ?  I use Mahout 0.7 and it works for me fine - check this gist https://gist.github.com/tuxdna/9808278